# Change Typeface of Tab titles - ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, typeface

Is it possible to change the typeface of the ActionBarSherlock Tab titles programmatically to a custom font?
I've searched around for a method but only come across where the typeface used is a default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine it would be similar to what I have here http://thehax.org/code-cuts/setting-a-custom-font-throughout-your-entire-app/

I extend textview and set the typeface there, but You should be able to get the textview object and do it there.

```
String otfName = “FrutigerLTStd-Cn.otf”;
               Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), otfName);
               this.setTypeface(font);
```